# How can i seed my database with datas from a graphql?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, graphql, apollo

I have retrieve datas from an **API** (https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/).
I wanted to know if it was possible to seed the datas that I have retrieved to a database as **PostgreSQL**, maybe through an **ORM** but I don't figure how. And if you have the answer and willing to guide me I'll appreciate.

Here is how I retrieved the datas:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { QUERY } from "../graphql/schema";

export default function AnimList() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }

  const medias = data.Page.media;

  return (
    <div className="mainGrid">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
        {medias.map((value) => {
      return (
        <div key={value.id} className="card">
        <img src={value.coverImage.medium} alt="placeholder" />
          <p>{value.title.userPreferred} </p>
        </div>
        )
    })}

    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You are misconcepting the frontend and backend, you retrieve your data in frontend, but it’s not recommended to directly connect frontend to database… Basically if you want to fetch the api and populate your data base from it it’s much more easier to create plane nodejs app and do that ther via script. This prolly where you want to start https://node-postgres.com/

Comment: This will also aid your quest https://supabase.com/

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I'm using Next.Js so I'll look how to do it with Next.